# How to show if a function is Lipshitz continous then it satisfies Lusin Nproperty

Tags: real-analysis

I wonder how to show this claim, any idea? Here, f is from [a,b] to $R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give a lot of details about your function so I will give you a result which might be the one you are looking for.
If a fuction is Lipshitz continuous it is absolutely continuous.

**Theorem of Banach-Zaretski** : Let $f$ be real bounded variations and continuous on the segment $[a,b]$. $f$ is absolutely continuous iff f satisfies Lusin N property.

You can find a proof here :[proof of theorem](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ErtmdgxSxA8C&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=Banach%20Zarecki%20Theorem&source=bl&ots=2RJFiaCavC&sig=V__u-QQPSSurVY826euuHOaoiPw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jwbDUoSiOLHMsQTW_IHoDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Banach%20Zarecki%20Theorem&f=false)

[image: screenshot of the proof]

Comment: But the link is not available.

Comment: Ok so it is the right theorem.
The link work for me, I will try to post a screenshot, wait a minute :).